# Existing Spring boot application to Tomcat 10

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat10

We currently have a `Spring boot` application running on `Tomcat 9`.

It is using `Spring boot version 2.1.5`. In order to make my application compatible with `Tomcat 10`, what should be the `Spring boot` version?

Will Spring boot be compatible with `Tomcat 10(jakarta.* changes)`? Or is it still in development?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No version of Spring at this time (neither Spring 5.3.x nor Spring Boot 2.5.x) supports Jakarta EE 9.

According to [this issue ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25354#issuecomment-875915960), you need to wait for Spring 6.x (2022) and Spring Boot 3.x.

**Edit:** It is official (cf. [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6)): support for Jakarta EE 9 will be available in Spring Boot 3 and Spring 6, but at the same time they will require Java 17.

**Edit2:** The first milestone releases (`3.0.0-M3` at the time of writing) are available in the Maven repository `https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/milestone`.