# Can't load my webpages using tomcat, servlets and spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlet-mapping

So I've been trying to load my webpages from a spring/servlet based java application that I've created and I keep getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error each time however Im positive I have hooked up all of xml servlet mappings and Java code correctly. There are no backend errors popping up other than the front end web page loading the 404 and saying `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`There are no errors and the paths that I have setup for the xml seem to be fine so Im not sure why my code is having trouble mapping the paths to the actual jsp files itself. Here is my project structure and code so far

[image]

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>

  <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

  <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

  </servlet>

  <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.christien" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
package com.christien;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    //controller method to show the initial form
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(){
        return "helloworld-form";
    }

    //controller method to process the form
    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(){
        return "helloworld";
    }

}
```

If anyone could help me as to what I'm doing wrong or possibly even redirect me to another useful stack post that would be great, thanks!

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using and are there any errors in the log files?

Comment: Im using version 10.0.12 and there are no errors in the logging files from what I can see

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying Spring 5.x on Tomcat 10.x with jakarta.\* package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217350/deploying-spring-5-x-on-tomcat-10-x-with-jakarta-package)

Comment: Spring 6.x (due Q4 2022), will be compatible with Tomcat 10. Cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68776180/11748454)

Answer (score 0):

By adding **element tags** to the beginning and end of the XML file may solve your issue. Like below

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<element>

<web-app>

  <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

  <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

  </servlet>

  <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

</element>
```

Comment: This isn't even a valid XML: if the document type is `<!DOCTYPE web-app`, the root XML element of the file must be `<web-app>` not `<element>`.